# Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync always returns Denied status

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I am following [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/get-location) to get user location in my UWP app but the following code always returns a `Denied` status.

```
var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
```

I have already **enabled "Location" capability in the app manifest**, but still no permission dialog is showing up whatsoever.

What else have I missed?

Comment: @mjwills did you even finish reading my question? I clearly stated that **"I have already enabled "Location" capability in the app manifest"**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to not only enable *Location capability* but also *Location service* in your Windows 10 settings.

To turn it on, go to *Settings > Location Privacy Settings* and then turn on the *Location service* toggle as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Note that when this system-wide **Location service** is on, even if the user denies your app from using his/her location, you can still get an imprecise location by enabling [`AllowFallbackToConsentlessPositions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator#Windows_Devices_Geolocation_Geolocator_AllowFallbackToConsentlessPositions) from `Geolocator`.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this. Thank you, it worked!